# Commutator relations for Propagators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

From Shankar,
$$[P,H]=0\rightarrow [P,U(t)]=0$$
where $P$ is the momentum operator, $H$ is the Hamiltonian, and $U(t)$ is the propagator to the Hamiltonian.

My first question is why does this follow?  Shankar says that the propagator is a function of the Hamiltonian, but from what I understand it is constructed from eigenvectors, and not from the Hamiltonian itself.

My second question is why would the commutator relation automatically hold for a function of $H$?  Is this only for relations where
$$[\Omega,H]=0$$
so for a function $\Lambda$ of $H$, by taking the Taylor expansion
$$[\Omega,\Lambda]=[\Omega,\lambda_0+\lambda H+\frac{\lambda}{2!}H^2+\cdots]=0$$
where $\lambda$ is a c number related to $\Lambda$.  If say $[\Omega,H]=\text{const}$, would that immediately imply $[\Omega,\Lambda]=\text{const}$?

My third question is for time dependent Hamiltonians, $[P,H(t)]=0$ must hold for all time in order for $[P,U(t)]=0$ to also hold.  Is this because if it didn't commute then the commutator would be a time dependent function,  $[P,H(t)]=f(t)$, so the propagator would no longer commute with $P$ (i.e. $[P,U(t)]=f(t)$)?

Comment: For t-independent *H*, you have $U(1)= \exp (-itH/\hbar)$, of course.  In   (2), commutation with *H* suffices for commutation with its powers. In (3), indeed commuting with *H(t)* for all t suffices for commutation with *U(t)*  to vanish, as this is now a time-ordered exponential.

Comment: @CosmasZachos so for (2) I get that the Taylor series commutes, I guess my question is that whether that is the reason why the propagator commutes, by expanding $\exp(-itH/\hbar)$ to see how if $P$ and $H$ commutes $U(t)$ will also commute.  However if the commutator equals a constant for $[P,H]$ then it will be a different constant for the commutator of $[P,U(t)]$?  Could you also elaborate what it means as a time-ordered exponential?

Comment: @CosmasZachos is my understanding for (1) and (2) correct though?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to go back and refresh your evaluations of commutators, like the Hadamard lemma and basic identities,
$$
e^A B e^{-A}= B + [A,B]+[A,[A,B]]/2!+ ... \\
[B,A^2]=\{ A, [B,A]\},
$$
etc. Now apply them to your items. You've muffed several points above, so I don't wish to rebuke them.

1. For a time-independent *H*, note $U(t)= \int \!\!dE~ |E\rangle e^{-itE/\hbar}\langle E|=\exp (-it H/\hbar)~~~\leadsto$
   $$
   U^{-1}PU-P=0, ~~\implies U^{-1} [P,U]=0 ~~\implies [P,U]=0.
   $$
2. See above. In general, the zero is useful, since you may prove recursively that
   $$[\Omega, H]=0~~\implies [\Omega, H^2]=0 \\ ~~\implies  [\Omega, H^3]=0~...~\implies [\Omega, H^n]=0, $$
   so also any function *f(H)*. Convince yourself this fails for a constant non vanishing commutator. That is why people use the Hadamard lemma in Lie groups. Just don't go there.
3. Most books work out the [time-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) for $[H(t),H(t')]\neq 0$,
   $$
   U(t)= \prod_0^t e^{a(t') \, dt'} \equiv
       \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left(
         e^{a(t_N) \, \Delta t} e^{a(t_{N-1}) \, \Delta t} \cdots
         e^{a(t_1) \, \Delta t} e^{a(t_0) \, \Delta t}
       \right),
    $$
   where the time moments  {$t_ , …, t_N$}  are defined as  *t<sub>i</sub> ≡ i Δt* for  *i=0, …, N* , and *Δt ≡t/N* , and  $a(t)\equiv -iH(t)/\hbar$.  Might look at (22) [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph215/TimeOrderedExp.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good, but I would like to give another point of view, by using the definition of the evolution operator as the solution of an operator-valued ODE.

With a time dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$, the propagator $U(t,t')$ is defined by :
$$i\hbar\partial_t U(t,t') = H(t)\quad \text{and} \quad U(t,t') = \mathbb I$$

Then, if $A$ is an operator with $[A,H(t)] = 0$ for all $t$, we have :
$$\partial_t[A,U(t,t')] = \left[A,\partial_t U(t,t')\right] = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[A,H(t)] = 0$$
together with $[A,U(t',t')]= [A,\mathbb I] = 0$, we get $[A,U(t,t') ]=0$ for all $t,t'$.